# Y Position of Tweenlite not moving

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

This is doing my head in. I have no idea why the first Tweenlite in this code isn't working, while the second is. I am trying to make a bejeweled clone for practice coding, and this is the function where I need the jewels to drop. The traces are correct, but the Y position isn't moving for the Tweenlite. What do you guys think is causing this problem?

```
    private function dropDownJewels():void
    {
        //trace(map[0]); // traces the x values
        tempInt = 0;
        for ( i=GV.GRID_SIZE_ROWS-1; i!==-1; i-- ) // a backward loop.
        {
            for ( j=GV.GRID_SIZE_COLS-1; j!==-1; j-- )
            {
                //trace(i + "  "  + j);
                //check the jewel to the bottom of this one and if that is gone, then move this gem down.
                if (!map[i][j].gone)
                {
                    map[i][j].jewelDropDist = countRowsBelow(i, j, 0, 1);
                    // now we want jewels above this one to drop with it... so...
                    for ( k=1; k<j+1; k ++)
                    {
                        if (map[i][j-k].gone) { break;}
                        //trace("DSAF");
                        map[i][j-k].jewelDropDist = map[i][j].jewelDropDist;
                        tempInt = j-k;
                        if (map[i][j-k].jewelDropDist >= 1) 
                        {
                            TweenLite.to(map[i][j-k], 10, {y: map[i][j-k].y + (map[i][j-k].jewelDropDist *( GV.JEWEL_HEIGHT + GV.JEWEL_SPACING ) ) });
                            //map[i][j-k].y += map[i][j-k].jewelDropDist *( GV.JEWEL_HEIGHT + GV.JEWEL_SPACING );
                            trace("COPIED: " +map[i][j-k].name + " jewel at " + i + "," + tempInt + " needs to drop " + map[i][j-k].jewelDropDist);
                        }
                    }

                    if (map[i][j].jewelDropDist >= 1) { trace(map[i][j].name + " jewel at " + i + "," + j + " needs to drop " + map[i][j].jewelDropDist); }

                    //map[i][j].gone = true;
                        TweenLite.to(map[i][j], 10, {y: map[i][j].y + (map[i][j].jewelDropDist *( GV.JEWEL_HEIGHT + GV.JEWEL_SPACING ) ) });

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. Do you actually tween the one of the `map[i][j]` by two tweens by accident?

Comment: hey man, what do you mean ? Do you mean if they were tweened before?

Comment: No, you might accidentally tween ONE object for ONE property with TWO different tweens. Check if so (check what objects get tweened each time you execute this code, if there is a duplicate, solve).

Comment: okay yeah that gave me a great lead. I put map[i][j-k].gone = true and problem fixed :D